# Prove that a group of even order must contain a odd number of elements of order 2.

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that a group of even order must contain a odd number of elements of order 2 and I know that if i take all the elements with order $>2$ that that subgroup has a even number of elements. But where do i go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that there is an even number of elements with order $>2$; since your group is of even order, there must be an even number of elements with order $\leq 2$. But there is only one element with order $1$; thus there is an odd number of elements with order $2$.

Comment: How do we now know that there must be an even number of order $\le2$?

Comment: There is an even number of elements and an even number of elements with order $>2$. And every elements has order either $>2$ or $\leq 2$...

Comment: Does a group of even order always have an even number of elements? (Just to be sure)

Comment: The order of a group *is* the number of elements...

Comment: In my book it says "... and the smallest positive integer m such that $x^m = e$ is called the order of x." Is this the same and if so what point might I be missing?

Comment: That's the definition of order of an element in the group; the order of a (finite) group is defined as the number of elements.